# Can't run gearmand after installing on OSX using homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, gearman

I just tried to install gearman on OSX 10.10 Yosemite. The installation looked like it worked fine.

`brew install gearman`

But when I tried to run the command to start the job server `gearmand -d` I just get `-bash: gearmand: command not found`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out the homebrew puts everything in `/usr/local/opt/gearman/bin` in your PATH (gearman and gearman-admin). But it puts `gearmand` in `/usr/local/opt/gearman/sbin`. Homebrew totally misses it.

I solved it by soft-linking to my /usr/local/bin.

`ln -s /usr/local/opt/gearman/sbin/gearmand /usr/local/bin`

Boom. Now `gearmand` is in your PATH.